# Getting 500 Internal Server Error from Account.getVirtualGuests()

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have been using a particular method for the past year and a half for loading the virtual guests from our account. Sometime in the past week, it broken.  The following code (using ruby gem 3.1.1) returns a 500 Internal Server Error:

```
  softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new()
  obj_svc = softlayer_client['Account']
  obj_svc = obj_svc.object_mask('mask[ id,tagReferences  ]')
  result = obj_svc.getVirtualGuests()
  result.each do |pre_obj|
    puts pre_obj.inspect
  end
```

But this does not:

```
  softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new()
  obj_svc = obj_svc.object_mask('mask[ id  ]')
  result = obj_svc.getVirtualGuests()
  result.each do |pre_obj|
    puts pre_obj.inspect
  end
```

Seems like tagReferences was broken recently, since this has been working for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reviewed your first block of code and it works OK. Nevertheless, the problem that you're facing might be due to the number of objects that the method's returning, either virtual guests or tag objects. This can be avoided using a result_limit(OFFSET, LIMIT) as in the next example:

```
OFFSET = 0
LIMIT = 5
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
softlayer_client = SoftLayer::Client.new(username: USERNAME, api_key: API_KEY)
obj_svc = softlayer_client['Account']
obj_svc = obj_svc.object_mask('mask[ id,tagReferences  ]')
obj_svc = obj_svc.result_limit(OFFSET, LIMIT)
result = obj_svc.getVirtualGuests()
result.each do |pre_obj|
  puts pre_obj.inspect
end
```

If it doesn't solve your problem, try downloading the latest softlayer ruby client gem (i.e. 3.2.1)

You could review the next link as well:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/How-Solve-Error-fetching-http-headers

Comment: Indeed there was too much data coming back. Perhaps we added more machines and tipped it over or tagReferences now returns a lot more data than it used to.  Either way, I both limited what comes back from tagReferences AND used the result_limit to select batches of 50.  All good now, thanks!