# Why do I keep getting a 500 error when I calling the SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice::getItems interface?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Recently I was developing a project that relied on the softlayer interface. I want get the invoice details about the bare metal server. But I keep getting a 500 error when I call the SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice::getItems interface. And other interfaces are normal.

regards~

code show as below:

```
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username="username",
                                          api_key="api_key",
                                          proxy="proxy")
sl_billing_invoice = client['Billing_Invoice']
try:
    result = sl_billing_invoice.getItems(id=id)
    print result
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as sl_exc:
    msg = 'result:(%s, %s)' % (sl_exc.faultCode, sl_exc.faultString)
    print msg
```

Return error message as blow:

> result:(500, 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely that your request is returning a big amount of data, this case commonly happens with invoices and billing items. In order to solve that issue you have the followings options:

1. Reduce the amount of data through object-masks or using object-filters.
2. Use pagination (result limits) in order to fetch less data in the request.

   `result = sl_billing_invoice.getItems(limit=50, offset=0, id=id)`

Softlayer doc and similar questions:

https://softlayer.github.io/blog/phil/how-solve-error-fetching-http-headers/

https://softlayer-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/client.html?highlight=limit#making-api-calls

[Softlayer getAllBillingItems stopped working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976335/softlayer-getallbillingitems-stopped-working)

[Getting 500 Internal Server Error from Account.getVirtualGuests()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131357/getting-500-internal-server-error-from-account-getvirtualguests)

[getInvoices method failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498926/getinvoices-method-failing/)

[Getting "error": "Internal Error" on Postman and getting error Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666868/getting-error-internal-error-on-postman-and-getting-error-can-not-deseriali/)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I got it. The interface is normal. Best regards~